# WCF Sessions on Windows Azure

Tags: wcf, session, authentication, azure

Our application architecture is as follows: 
1) WCF service acts as a facade layer and sits on top of Service, Business Logic and Data Access layer
2) Every client, be it an MVC/ASP.NET, or any other type of application has a ClientTag that first needs to be authenticated and issued an "access token". This token is then passed by the client with every message into the Facade layer
3) The system will be hosted on Windows Azure

This would have been easy to implement with WCF sessions like so:
1) Client initiates a call to WCF to get the token (Client to WCF Session is established, thus every subsequent communication is part of the same "conversation")
2) WCF authenticates the ClientTag, issues the token, and stores it as a local variable
3) Client stores the token in it's own Session and pass it to WCF with every request

Where it breaks down is the fact that Azure (due to its high-availability/load-balancing nature) doesn't support WCF sessions. So, the questions is how do we implement this.

One solution is to use AppFabric caching to imitate session state in WCF layer. We would store the Access Token there and then validate it against what the client passes in. The problem with this is that there is no concurrency between client and WCF. So, we would have to advance WCF session timeout on every request from the same client but we'd want to avoid updating the cache on every request (it could be hundreds/sec).

Any suggestions? Has anyone implemented anything similar to this on Azure. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. It's not only authentication that would happen on the server, but also custom authorization for each client. (Some client might have access to some functions, and others might not).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the middle of implementing something directly similar to this, but using OAuth 2.0 as the authentication architecture through ACS.

The model I'm following is shamelessly <strike>stolen</strike> copied from an MSDN sample here: https://connect.microsoft.com/site1168/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=35417. This assumes the client has a user interface, so the user can present some kind of username and password either directly or through some third-party identity provider.

The advantage of this approach is that the WCF layer doesn't need to use any kind of session state, so there's no tedious mucking about with machine keys or whatnot. You'll still get something that can be mapped to an `IPrincipal`, however, so if you want you can create a custom `RoleProvider` and use declarative roles in the usual way.

Note the sample uses old-school ASP.NET, and has a dependency on an opaque (and possibly rather buggy) assembly `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.Oauth`. And, unless I'm missing something, I've not seen this released anywhere else (e.g. as part of Windows Identity Foundation) so I suspect it's rather new.

An alternative approach could again be to use ACS, this time to authenticate a SAML token, again following the OAuth 2.0 protocols. Details and sample code is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh127795.aspx. That may be better suited to a system with no UI.